# CentOS : showing error message No space left on device

Tags: linux, centos

I am using CentOS-5.5 its not stasting. while booting its showing "GDM could not write a new authorization entry to disk.Possible out of diskspace.Error: No space left on device" if press  then showing  one more message "Could not start X server (your graphical environment) due to some internal error. please contact your system administrator or check your syslog to diagnose. In meantime this display will be disabled.Please restart GDM when the problem is corrected.
 and if check filesystem uses by "df -h" its showing

```
Filesystem             Size  used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVo100 
                       285GB 285GB 0   100%    /
/dev/sda1               99M   12M 82M  13%     /boot
tmfs                   997M   0    997M  0%    /dev/shm
```

Comment: As a point of fact, the [FAQ] clearly states that this site is for professional systems administrators.  Given that you don't know how to delete files it's a pretty good guess that you are not a professional administrator.

Answer (score 4):

It's true. You ran out of disk space. Delete some unnecessary files and then try again.

Comment: how to delete sir O dint know commands

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can delete files with the command

```
rm /path/to/file
```

You can delete folder with the parameter -r

```
rm -r /path/to/folder
```

Might be your home folder that is using a lot of space.

With

```
du -sh /*
```

You can see what folder is using the most space.

With

```
ls -lh /path
```

You can see the file sizes.